# Javascript window-alert gets displayed before my function has run

Tags: javascript, alert

Hi im currently working on a simple TicTacToe for a school  Project. When someone wins the game i want it to be displayed in a window.alert message box. I now have the issue,  that when a player wins the message is displayed before the color of the clicked box changes. i do not understand why this is happening. To confuse me even more if i debug the code and set a breakpoint where the color is meant to change then it works in the correct order even though i changed nothing about the code. I would appreciate any pointers as to why this is happening and how i can solve it.

Comment: What about code?

Comment: Please post your code structure.

Comment: change line 37.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because even when the color change is triggered first. There is a delay it requires to complete the action on DOM. Since color change in DOM is an asynchronous function your next alert message statement gets executed. If you want to avoid this do work around like setting variable when color is changed and using that to display the message or use setInterval() function to monitor the change

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

"UI" changes may be delayed. Try setting a very short timer and displaying the alert in the delayed function.

Comment: Thanks for the answer I tried doing this i set a timeout for 1000 miliscecs but it still has the same result.